# How can $ i $ be distinguished from $ - i $?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Mathematicians designate one solution to $x^2 = -1$ as $i$ and the other as $-i$.  Would anybody notice if we switched their identities?  Any polynomial $p(x)$ with a complex root will also have its conjugate as a root.  Is there any equation in real numbers with a complex solution that does not have its conjugate as another solution?

Comment: Complex conjugation is a continuous field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$, so no.

Comment: See Stewart Shapiro's article, An "i" for an i (http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=8685119&fileId=S1755020311000347), in which he analyzes the interesting and perplexing philosophical issue arising here, namely, how it is that mathematicians seem able to treat $i$ as a definite description, in light of the indiscernibility arising by conjugation.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Re Shapiro's article, I have a great deal of difficulty seeing the point.  If I have a theory with the single axiom $x=x$, then all elements of all models are indistinguishable.  If I have a much richer theory, things become distinguishable.  It turns out that the theory of the real numbers is not strong enough to distinguish $i$ from $-i$ but the theory of the complex numbers is.  This makes the $i/-i$ distinction no different from any other distinction --- *every* pair of things is indistinguishable given a sufficiently weak theory.  Have I missed something?

Comment: The theory of the complex numbers (in the language of fields, say) does not distinguish $i$ from $-i$, unless you add a constant symbol for $i$, which of course is the point under discussion. The philosophical issue here is that we all go around talking about $i$ and $2i+3$ and so on, but there is no mechanism at all to ensure that what I call $i$ is the same as what you call $i$, or indeed the same as what I called $i$ yesterday, or two lines earlier in my argument. But meanwhile, we write equations that rely on the identity of those referents, not just on their automorphic nature.

Comment: But on to your larger point, yes, the case of $i$ and $-i$ is just one of many common cases of indiscernibility, and Shapiro is trying to grapple with the general problem, not just the case of $i$. But the case of $i$ is a little special because it seems that we mathematicians do definitely treat $i$ as a definite description, in a way more so than in other cases of indiscernibility.

Comment: Meanwhile, I should say that I don't actually agree with Shapiro's account here, since my view is that we habitually operate, perhaps without even thinking about it much, in a mathematical realm having additional structure in which the objects become discernible.

Comment: @JDH:  Yes, when I said "theory of the complex numbers", I meant "with a constant symbol for $i$", and should have been clear about that.  But I still don't understand why $i$ is a particularly interesting case.  There are theories in which you and I are not distinguishable, but that doesn't stop people from treating "JDH" as a definite description.  (There are, of course, other theories in which we're distinguishable.)  Is that another instance of exactly the same problem, or is there still something special about $i$ that makes it more interesting than JDH?

Comment: The question is too loosely phrased to answer. What is "an equation in real numbers" and what is "the conjugate of an equation in real numbers"?

Comment: @WillO Yes, one can make all kinds of examples, and as I mentioned, the philosophical work is concerned with the general case. Meanwhile, however, I do believe (along with Shapiro) that the case of $i$ is more striking than many other cases. We have the name $i$ for what appears to be a rigid designator, and everyone uses it universally as if it were, yet they also agree that $-i$ would have been just as good a choice, especially those who have a structuralist outlook. It is an interesting conundrum for the theory of names to see how this works, and I don't think it is easily dismissed.

Comment: @JDH:  Thanks for this.

Comment: This is my first question on Math Overflow, and I would just like to express appreciation for the quickness and appropriateness of the response.  My question was indeed the same as the previous one.  It was very helpful to be able to review the responses to that question.